# how to raise events for ICommand in C# wpf application

Tags: c#

below code how to raise events for ICommand in C# wpf application

```
public ICommand CancelCommand
 {
 get { return new DelegateCommandWrapper(CancelButton); }
 }
```

Comment: Like `CancelCommand.Execute(null);`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'raise events'? Do you mean call the command??? You should BIND the command to a button or something, in your UI. Something like;

```
 <Button Command = "{Binding CancelCommand}" Content="Cancel"/>
```

In your XAML file...

Answer (score 0):

From Codebehind/ViewModel, you simply do

```
CancelCommand.Execute(null);
```